# What is the story of Madalasa?

Tags: puranas

Who was Madalasa? What is the story of Ritudhwaj and Madalasa?
Is it true that she's known as a great mother in Hinduism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Kuvalayasva:**

[Here](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-markandeya-purana/d/doc117052.html) is the story of King Ritudhwaj in Markandeya Puran Canto XX:

> “It is the son of Śatru-jit, dear father, famed by name as Ṛtadhvaja, shapely, upright in conduct, a hero, proud, kind of speech, no sneaking tale-bearer,[6] eloquent, learned, friendly, a mine of excellencies, an honourer of the honour-worthy, intelligent, modest, adorned with courtesy. Our mind, [Page 111] being ravished by attendance on him, affection for him and pleasure with him, finds no delight in the Naga-world or the air-world.[7] By separation from him chill Pātāla does not tend to warm us, dear father; through union with him the sun by day tends to gladden us.”

**Madalasa:** Here is What Madalasa's friend Kundala told Ritudhwaja About Madalasa.

> ‘The king of the Gandharvas is named Visvāvasu, and this is his beautiful-browed daughter called Madālasś. The son of Vajra-ketu, a fierce Dānava, the cleaver of his foes, was named Pātāla-ketu, a dweller within Pātāla. He, raising an illusion of darkness, carried off this maiden when she was in her garden, unattended by me, and brought her here, the villain. On the coming thirteenth day of the lunar fortnight, it was foretold, an Asura shall carry her off; but he does not [Page 116] deserve the lovely-limbed maiden, any more than a śūdra deserves to hear the Veda. And when the day was over, Surabhi said to the maiden who was ready to kill herself,

[Here](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-markandeya-purana/d/doc117053.html) Is How Madalasa And Kuvalayasva Married in Markandeya Puran Canto XXI:

> I am ready to comply,’ thus spoke the king’s son to her, O father. And she thought of him, the large-thighed[4] hero, the chief of his race. And he taking fuel and kūsa grass, accepted her immediately, through affection for Madālasā and through respect for Kuṇḍalā. Kindling fire, he sacrificed, being conversant with the mantras, and caused the blessed maiden to take part in the marriage ceremony. And as he had come, he departed then, being a wise man, to his own hermitage-abode for the purpose of practising austerities.
>   “And the companion said to the maiden ‘My wishes are fulfilled, O lovely-faced one. Now that I have seen thee, resplendent in beauty, wedded to this husband, I will perform matchless austerities, with a mind at ease; and, having my sins washed away in the waters of the sacred pilgrimage-places, I shall not again become such as I am now.” “And then bending courteously she addressed the king’s son, being desirous to go, yet shaken in her speech through love for her friend.